# JqueryUI - How to disable track handle on click and allow sliding/dragging handle and move one of 3 handles?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, slider

I have JQuery UI slider with 3 handles.
I need disable click (rewrite event for clicking on slider), but allow sliding on handle mousedrag.

I'm trying something like this, but it's not working (sliding blocked too).:

```
$('#controls #timeline').unbind('mousedown');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sWWTZ/4/

here is jsfiddle with 3 handles. I need move only middle handle without left and right on click

update:   fiddle full example with ranges.

I found in original slider source code how he is selecting handle:

```
  _mouseCapture: function( event ) {
       ...........
       this.handles.each(function( i ) {
        var thisDistance = Math.abs( normValue - that.values(i) );
        if (( distance > thisDistance ) ||
            ( distance === thisDistance &&
                (i === that._lastChangedValue || that.values(i) === o.min ))) {
            distance = thisDistance;
            closestHandle = $( this );
            index = i;
        }
    });
       ...........
  }
```

Any ideas, how i can select index 0 ?

Comment: Please post a complete code example. A jsFiddle.net example would also help.

Comment: @xercool you should be doing this `$('#controls #timeline').unbind('click');`

Comment: @xercool you mean you want to disable the left and right and have enable only middle?

Comment: yes, only middle handle

Comment: this is combination of slider range and simple slider.

Comment: @xercool Out of curiosity Then you can have get slider with single one.

Comment: i need set ranges for video file duration and position on one slider control.

Comment: `.on` and `.off` is preferred to `.bind` and `.unbind`.